# PHP: Function not returning Array

Tags: php

Can someone help me out? I cannot see it. The function below is not returning the array. The `print_r($list)`(above the `return`) prints the array on the screen. But the `print_r($files)`returns an empty array....

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    $i = 0;
    $list = array();
    foreach ( $ffs as $ff ){
        if ( $ff != '.' && $ff != '..' ){
            if ( strlen($ff)>=5 ) {
                if ( substr($ff, -4) == '.mp4' ) {
                    $value = $dir.'/'.$ff;
                    $list[] = $value;
                }
            }
            if( is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff) )
                    listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
        }
    }

    print_r($list);  // Returns the full array with values
    return $list;
}
$files = listFolderFiles($_POST['path']);
print_r($files) // Returns an empty array..... :(:(
```

Comment: what is that ? `($_POST('path'))`? a typo? `$_POST['path']`

Comment: My mistake, made a typo when I posted the question. Was written right in the PHP file though, so still not working

Comment: I notice that the $list returns two times an array..... One filled and one empty. Maybe it runes the listFolderFiles too many times?

Comment: So, when you run it like this, then both `print_r`s are called, and one prints out the desired output, and one does not? Is it possible, that the `POST` value doesn't arrive/is not correct?

Comment: My guess is that it finds something in the `if( is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff) )` part. But there you are ignoring its return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recursion call doesn't handle the returned array:

```
listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
```

You need to merge the array here:

```
$list = array_merge($list, listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff) );
```

Comment: @ErikVandeVen I updated the answer, try it like this.